# Show that $\tau_c$ is a topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

$\tau_c$ is defined as follows:

> $\tau_c:= \{ U\subset X \mid X\setminus U \; \text{is countable or}\; X\setminus U =X\}$

And I was wondering if this strategy works:

Let $I=\{\alpha \mid X\setminus U_\alpha \; \text{is countable}\}$ and $J=\{ \alpha \mid X\setminus U_\alpha =X\}$. Then, to see that the union of arbitrary elements $U_\alpha$ is in $\tau_c$:

$$\begin{align*}
X\setminus \bigcup_{\alpha}U_\alpha & = X\setminus \left[ \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha \cup \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha \right] = \left[ X\setminus \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}U_\alpha \right]\cap \left[X\setminus \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha \right]\\
&= \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}\left(X\setminus U_\alpha \right) \cap \bigcap_{\alpha\in J}\left( X\setminus U_\alpha\right) = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} \left(X\setminus U_\alpha \right) \cap X\\
&= \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}\left(X\setminus U_\alpha \right)
\end{align*}$$
which is an intersection of countable sets, and therefore, it is countable. The same work would show that finite intersection is also in $\tau_c$. My question then is if this is right, that is, can I split the union in two index sets $I$ and $J$ as I did? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you really mean "$X\setminus U = X$"? The only set $U\subset X$ satisfying this condition is $U=\varnothing$.

Comment: @MPW Yes. And well, that's obligated, since we need the empty set to be in $\tau_c$.

Comment: Indeed. However, it seems a bit obfuscatory to write it that way (why not just "$U=\varnothing$"?). Just checking.

Comment: It is practically immediate that $X\setminus\bigcup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}=X\setminus\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_{\alpha}$. I think you better start from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A split up in cocountable sets and the (unique) empty set (wich also belongs to $\tau_c$) is in essence okay.

You end up by saying: "wich is an intersection of countable sets, and therefore is countable...". However, that is not necessarily the case if $I=\varnothing$. Then you end up with an empty intersection (wich is $X$ itself and $X$ does not have to be countable).

1) $\tau_c$ contains $\varnothing$ and $X$ as elements.

- Since $X\setminus\varnothing=X$ we conclude that $\varnothing\in\tau_c$.
- Since $X\setminus X=\varnothing$ is countable we conclude that $X\in\tau_c$.

2) $\tau_c$ is closed under arbitrary unions.

Let $U_{\alpha}\in\tau_c$ for $\alpha\in A$ and $U:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_{\alpha}$.  We discern the following cases:

- For some $\alpha_0\in A$ we have $U_{\alpha_0}\neq\varnothing$. Then $X\setminus U_{\alpha_0}$ is countable and consequently $X\setminus U\subseteq X\setminus U_{\alpha_0}$ is countable, so that $U\in\tau_c$.
- For every $\alpha\in A$ we have $U_{\alpha}=\varnothing$ and consequently $U=\varnothing\in\tau_c$.

3) $\tau_c$ is closed under finite intersections.

Let $V,W\in\tau_c$. We discern the following cases:

- $V=\varnothing$ or $W=\varnothing$. Then consequently $V\cap W=\varnothing\in\tau_c$.
- $V\neq\varnothing$ and $W\neq\varnothing$. Then consequently $X\setminus V$ and $X\setminus W$ are countable, so that also $X\setminus(V\cap W)=(X\setminus V)\cup(X\setminus W)$ is countable. We conclude that $V\cap W\in\tau_c$.

Comment: Thank you! Much clearer now. So I can split up in two index sets like I did? (Though useless, I'd like to know if I can do such thing as it might be helpful some time in the future)

Comment: In principle you can. But it is good to keep in mind that $\varnothing$ is then the only member of one of the index sets. A split up in $\varnothing$ and "the rest" is more obvious. Index sets will not harm, but if their use is not really paying off then I would avoid them.